# Using FontAwesome or any other webfonts in the Xamarin AppShell TabBar Icon Property

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, font-awesome, xamarin.forms.shell

I have FontAwesome setup in my Xamarin.Forms(5.0) app (I'm using a bottom tabbed template from Microsoft).

I can display an icon in an image on one of the pages with no issues. I cannot seem to get one of the font icons to show in a TabBar element.

In the template there are two navigation elements; "about" and "browse". Those icons referenced appear to be .png files that are added into the specific iOS and Android projects. I want to reference webfont icons instead.

Here is my code for the AppShell.xaml. Can anyone see anything wrong with this? All the code you see below is template generated except for the `local2` namespace declaration and the "shows" `ShellContent` item.

`FontAwesomeBrands` is just a class that was generated from the `.otf` file using IconFont2Code website.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
           xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Business.Mobile.Views"
           xmlns:local2="clr-namespace:Business.Mobile"
           Title="Business.Mobile"
           x:Class="Business.Mobile.AppShell">
    
        <Shell.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
                    <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                    <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
                    <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
                    <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                    <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
                    <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
                <Style TargetType="FlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Shell.Resources>
    
        <TabBar>
            <ShellContent Title="About" Icon="icon_about.png" Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
            <ShellContent Title="Browse" Icon="icon_feed.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
            <ShellContent Title="Shows" Icon="{x:Static local2:FontAwesomeBrands.Audible}"  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
        </TabBar>
    
        <!--
            If you would like to navigate to this content you can do so by calling
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//LoginPage");
        -->
        <TabBar>
            <ShellContent Route="LoginPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" />
        </TabBar>
    
    </Shell>
```

This is in my AssemblyInfo.cs file.

```
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
    
    [assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    [assembly: ExportFont("fa-brands-400.otf", Alias = "FaBrands")]
```

Everything is in the root of the shared project. The `fa-brands-400.otf` file has its property set to `EmbeddedResource`. And again, it's working with an Image I added to the AboutPage.xaml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify that you are using `FontImageSource` to be able to specify the `Glyph` and `FontFamily` properties, otherwise by default it will look for Local images by the string you specified.

```xml
<TabBar>
    <ShellContent Title="About" Icon="icon_about.png" Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
    <ShellContent Title="Browse" Icon="icon_feed.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />

  <ShellContent Title="Shows">
      <ShellContent.Icon>
           <FontImageSource FontFamily="FaBrands"
                            Glyph="{x:Static local2:FontAwesomeBrands.Audible}"/>
      </ShellContent.Icon>
 </ShellContent.Icon>
</TabBar>
```

Comment: It's weird, I can use FontImageSource in other places, but as ShellContent.Icon I only get a little square, indicating something bugged out...

Comment: @JohanDanforth the square means "not found" check your unicode and the font style (regular or solid)

Comment: @JohanDanforth Did you find out why you got a square? - as I'm getting that too. Same here FontImageSource works elsewhere in About page.